# Use fields from Mariaex.Result struct

Tags: mysql, elixir, ecto

I have written an Elixir script which sends a MySQL query to my database using the Mariaex library. The query works perfectly. Now, I want to use the `num_rows` field returned in the Mariaex.Result struct in my script. The code snippet is something like this:-

```
if {:ok, %Mariaex.Result{num_rows: nil}} do
    IO.puts "Query Unsuccessful"
else
    IO.puts "Query Successful"
end
```

I know the if-condition does not work properly. The goal of the condition is to check whether `num_rows` is 0 or not. How should I modify the condition, so that the above code snippet works correctly?
This is the GitHub link for Mariaex: https://github.com/xerions/mariaex

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching using `case`:

```
case execute_query() do
  {:ok, %Mariaex.Result{num_rows: nil}} ->
     IO.puts "Query Unsuccessful"
  _ ->
     IO.puts "Query Successful"
end
```

You probably want to match `{:error, error}` as well:

```
case execute_query() do
  {:ok, %Mariaex.Result{num_rows: nil}} ->
     IO.puts "Query Unsuccessful"
  {:error, error}
     IO.puts "Error!"
  _ ->
    IO.puts "Query Successful"
end
```

You can change the `nil` above to `0` if you want to check for `0` instead.

Comment: The codes are not working. The first one gives rise to an error "undefined function execute_query/0". And the second one does not work because there is no variable called "error". If you want the error, you need to use the Mariaex.Error stuct. By the way, I know the problem is not with the whole code. I just need help to construct the if-condition, i.e., this part: {:ok, %Mariaex.Result{num_rows: nil}}.